# Unbound setting up a secure local DNS server

Tags: networking, dns, unbound

I don't trust public DNS servers specially because there is a possibility of government hijacking in my country. So basically I want to setup a local unbound server on my laptop which connects directly to root name servers for DNS lookups.

Currently I use all the default values in unbound.conf, I've just added this line:

> root-hints: "root.hints"

which is the file I got from get one from https://www.internic.net/domain/named.cache

Is that enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root hints are built-in to unbound so you don't even need that.

Here's a basic local-only resolving config:

```
server:
    interface: 127.0.0.1
    interface: ::1
    verbosity: 1
    use-caps-for-id: yes
    statistics-interval: 0
    qname-minimisation: yes
```

That's a very basic config that will work to resolve DNS names.  Then all you have to do is use 127.0.0.1 as your nameserver in the laptop's network configuration.

Beyond that, you'll probably run into places where this won't work because you are blocked on port 53 from talking to nameservers other than the locally supplied ones (i.e., what you get via DHCP).  This has become quite common in coffee shops and the like.  Good luck.

Note that if you're running a Debian-based distro, the default config when you install the unbound package will "just work" and is similarly configured as above.